# como puedo Abrir una pagina externa con un WebView

Tags: android, eclipse

Mi proyecto trata de un `tabhost` el cual una de las pestañas me debe llevar a una pagina web externa...
    para ello utilice un `webview`

esto me marca el logcat:

> 04-26 20:16:07.298: E/chromium(1402): [ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(153)]
>   No suitable EGL configs found. 04-26 20:16:07.308: E/chromium(1402):
>   [ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(620)] GLSurfaceEGL::InitializeOneOff failed.
>   04-26 20:16:07.308: E/chromium(1402): [ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(153)]
>   No suitable EGL configs found. 04-26 20:16:07.308: E/chromium(1402):
>   [ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(620)] GLSurfaceEGL::InitializeOneOff failed.
>   04-26 20:16:07.308: E/chromium(1402):
>   [ERROR:gpu_info_collector.cc(86)] gfx::GLSurface::InitializeOneOff()
>   failed 04-26 20:16:07.348: W/chromium(1402):
>   [WARNING:proxy_service.cc(888)] PAC support disabled because there is
>   no system implementation 04-26 20:16:07.858: D/dalvikvm(1402):
>   GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 33K, 2% free 8536K/8648K, paused 43ms, total 43ms
>   04-26 20:16:08.828: I/Choreographer(1402): Skipped 58 frames!  The
>   application may be doing too much work on its main thread. 04-26
>   20:16:08.948: D/gralloc_goldfish(1402): Emulator without host-side GPU
>   emulation detected. 04-26 20:16:10.508: I/chromium(1402):
>   [INFO:simple_index_file.cc(397)] Simple Cache Index is being restored
>   from disk. 04-26 20:16:14.748: D/dalvikvm(1402): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed
>   525K, 6% free 9935K/10536K, paused 97ms, total 107ms 04-26
>   20:16:16.058: W/AwContents(1402): nativeOnDraw failed; clearing to
>   background color. 04-26 20:16:16.778: W/AwContents(1402): nativeOnDraw
>   failed; clearing to background color. 04-26 20:16:16.908:
>   W/AwContents(1402): nativeOnDraw failed; clearing to background color.
>   04-26 20:16:17.028: E/AndroidProtocolHandler(1402): Unable to open
>   asset URL: file:///android_asset/imagenes/desierto.jpg 04-26
>   20:16:17.088: W/AwContents(1402): nativeOnDraw failed; clearing to
>   background color. 04-26 20:16:17.268: W/AwContents(1402): nativeOnDraw
>   failed; clearing to background color. 04-26 20:16:17.728:
>   I/Choreographer(1402): Skipped 30 frames!  The application may be
>   doing too much work on its main thread. 04-26 20:16:18.888:
>   I/Choreographer(1402): Skipped 53 frames!  The application may be
>   doing too much work on its main thread. 04-26 20:16:24.128:
>   E/AndroidProtocolHandler(1402): Unable to open asset URL:
>   file:///android_asset/imagenes/desierto.jpg 04-26 20:17:48.028:
>   I/chromium(1402): [INFO:CONSOLE(138)] "Uncaught TypeError: Object
>    has no method 'forEach'", source: https://ovacen.com/desarrollo-sustentable-concepto-ejemplos-de-proyectos/
>   (138) 04-26 20:28:52.978: E/AndroidProtocolHandler(1402): Unable to
>   open asset URL: file:///android_asset/imagenes/desierto.jpg

Esto es lo que dice mi código:

```
    activity main:

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        tools:context="com.example.ecologia.MainActivity" >

        <TabHost
            android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TabWidget
                    android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
                </TabWidget>

                <FrameLayout
                    android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/Inicio"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:orientation="vertical"

                         >

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/ImagenEcosistemas"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:src="@drawable/portada" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/Ecosistemas"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        >
                     <include
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            layout="@layout/contenido1" 
                            android:id="@+id/some_id_if_needed"/>

                    </LinearLayout>



                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/Desarrollo"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"

                         >

                        <include
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            layout="@layout/contenido2" 
                            android:id="@+id/DesarrolloSustentable"/>

                    </LinearLayout>
                </FrameLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </TabHost>

    </RelativeLayout>


    Main Activity:

    package com.example.ecologia;









    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.os.Build;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.webkit.WebSettings.PluginState;
    import android.webkit.WebView;
    import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

    import android.widget.AdapterView;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.widget.Spinner;
    import android.widget.TabHost;
    import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;


    public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnItemSelectedListener {

        public TabHost tabs;
        public Spinner SpinTipo,SpinEco;
        public WebView webEcosistemas;   
        public ImageView ImagenEcosistemas;
        private WebView webDesarrollo;

         public ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>adaTipoEcosistema;

         public ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adaTerrestre;

         public ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adaAcuatico;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


            SpinTipo = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.SpinTipo);
            SpinEco = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.SpinEco);
            webEcosistemas = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webEcosistemas);
            webDesarrollo = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webDesarrollo);
            View includedLayout = findViewById(R.id.DesarrolloSustentable);
            View includedLayout1 = findViewById(R.id.some_id_if_needed);
            webDesarrollo.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            webDesarrollo.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
            webDesarrollo  . loadUrl ( "https://ovacen.com/desarrollo- 
            sustentable-concepto-ejemplos-de-proyectos/" );
            webDesarrollo.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()
           {
                public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view,String url){
                    Intent web = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(("https://ovacen.com/desarrollo-sustentable-concepto-ejemplos-de-proyectos/")));
                    startActivity(web);
                    return false;
                }
           });












            adaTipoEcosistema= ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, 
                  R.array.Ecosistema,
                  android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
            adaTerrestre = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                      R.array.Terrestre,
                      android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
            adaAcuatico  =  ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                      R.array.Acuatico,
                      android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

      adaTipoEcosistema.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
      adaTerrestre.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
      adaAcuatico.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

      SpinTipo.setAdapter(adaTipoEcosistema);
      SpinEco.setAdapter(adaTerrestre);




      SpinTipo.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
      SpinEco.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

      webEcosistemas.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/desierto.html");


      tabs = (TabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
            tabs.setup();

      TabHost.TabSpec spec;


      spec = tabs.newTabSpec("Inicio");

      spec.setIndicator("",getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.inicio));

      spec.setContent(R.id.Inicio);
      tabs.addTab(spec);


      spec = tabs.newTabSpec("Ecosistemas");

      spec .setIndicator("",getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ecosistema));

      spec .setContent(R.id.Ecosistemas);
      tabs.addTab(spec);


      spec = tabs.newTabSpec("Desarrollo Sustentable");

      spec .setIndicator("",getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.desarrollo));

      spec .setContent(R.id.Desarrollo);
      tabs.addTab(spec);

      tabs.setCurrentTab(0);
    }






        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_settings:
                finish();
                break;
            }
            return true;


        }

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3)  {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (arg0.getId()==R.id.SpinTipo){
                switch(SpinTipo.getSelectedItemPosition()){
                case 0:
                       SpinTipo.setAdapter(adaTerrestre);
                       webEcosistemas.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/desierto.html");

                       break;
                case 1:
                       SpinTipo.setAdapter(adaAcuatico);
                       webEcosistemas.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/oceano.html");

                       break;
                }
              }


                if (arg0.getId()==R.id.SpinEco){
                    switch(SpinTipo.getSelectedItemPosition()){
                    case 0:
                        switch(SpinEco.getSelectedItemPosition()){ 
                        case 0:
                            webEcosistemas.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/tundra.html");

                            break;
                        case 1:
                            webEcosistemas.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/taiga.html");

                            break;
                        case 2:
                            webEcosistemas.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/bosque.html");

                            break;
                        case 3:
                            webEcosistemas.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/selva.html");

                            break;

                        case 4:
                            webEcosistemas.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/desierto.html");

                            break;

                        }
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        switch (SpinEco.getSelectedItemPosition()){
                        case 0:
                            webEcosistemas.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/oceano.html");

                            break;
                        case 1:
                            webEcosistemas.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/rio.html");


                        }
                        break;
                    }


                }
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    }


    contenido1:

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/TEcosistemas" />

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/SpinTipo"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/Ecosistemas" />

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/SpinEco"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>

        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/webEcosistemas"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="160dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/desierto" />

    </LinearLayout>

    contenido2:

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/webDesarrollo"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

En cuanto al error, se debe a que estas tratando de cargar un recurso que se encuentra dentro de assets, asegura que se encuentra el recurso o elimina el llamado a esta linea:

```
  webEcosistemas.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/desierto.html");
```

esto se indica en el `LogCat`:

> AndroidProtocolHandler(1402): Unable to open asset URL:
>   file:///android_asset/imagenes/desierto.jpg

---

Estas tratando de abrir la pagina en el browser del dispositivo al cargar en el `WebView`, esto es incorrecto :

```
 webDesarrollo.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()
           {
                public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view,String url){
                    Intent web = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(("https://ovacen.com/desarrollo-sustentable-concepto-ejemplos-de-proyectos/")));
                    startActivity(web);
                    return false;
                }
           });
```

Si deseas cargar la página dentro del `WebView`, no necesitas realizar un `Intent` , realizalo de esta forma:

```
  webDesarrollo.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()
               {
                    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view,String url){
                    view.loadUrl(url);
                    return true;
                    }
               });
```

o simplemente:

```
webDesarrollo.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
```

---

No olvides el permiso de internet en tu `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: Tampoco me funciona :c

Comment: @Alucard que no te funciona, que muesta, ¿Tienes los permisos de internet?

Comment: Si puse los permisos para que acceda a internet